# Remember jQuery hide or show after page refresh and setting up the Jquery cookie plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ScreenSizeHis = $.cookie(ScreenSizeHis);
    $("#arrow").bind('click', function(){
        $('#naviclosed').fadeIn("fast");
        $(window).unbind('resize');
    });
    $('#naviclosed').bind('click', function () {
        $('#naviclosed').fadeOut("fast");
        if ((ScreenSizeHis = $.cookie('ScreenSizeHis')) != undefined) {
            $(window).bind('resize', ScreenSize);
        }
    });
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    ScreenSize();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
 windowwidth = $(window).width();
if (windowwidth < 1040) {
    $('#naviclosed').fadeIn("fast");
}
if (windowwidth >= 1040) {
      $('#naviclosed').fadeOut("fast");
}
});
function ScreenSize()  {
  windowsize = $(window).width();
    if (windowsize < 1040) {
      $('#naviclosed').fadeIn("fast");
    }
    if (windowsize >= 1040) {
    $('#naviclosed').fadeOut("fast"); 
    }
}
```

Okay, the buttons are not even working after I put the cookie plugin.

Comment: You never actually create the cookie

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie by providing more arguments to `$.cookie`.  A single argument is used for retrieval:

```
//name, value, additional -- expire cookie in 30 days
$.cookie('ScreenSizeHis', ScreenSizeHis, {expires: 30});
```